# What is this white runoff on my brick siding?

Tags: brick

[image]

The home was built in 2021 and I moved into it 2 months ago. Just noticed this on the side of the home only in this place. What is this? Does it need to be fixed, if so how? Thank you very much! As a new homeowner I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Might be: https://www.allbrickandstone.com/brick-and-stone-advice/efflorescence/

Comment: Seems like it may be efflorescence. Wasn't sure if it was some lime runoff or anything else. How do I remedy this?

Comment: @HippyHoHo mechanically (brush or pressure washer), or chemically (try a vinegar solution).